# Dynamically styling pseudo elements with angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, pseudo-element

I have a `div` like below:

```
<div class="circle-icon"><span class="icon icon-loanaccount"></span></div>
```

and this `div` tag has the following styles:

```
.circle-icon {      
  background: #db552d none repeat scroll 0 0;      
  width: 50px;
  &::after{
    border-bottom: 5px solid #db552d;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;        
  }&:before{
     border-bottom: 5px solid #db552d;
     content: "";
     height: 0;        
   }      
}
```

how can I dynamically style `border-bottom` with angular, suppose that I have the color I want to use in `scope.borderColor` ?

Comment: I am not sure if i understood your question properly but you cannot select pseudo element with JS but you can inherit the style from the parent in example i have added border-color to parent and inherited the color to child i.e pseudo element https://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/gqzt3w05/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-style` is your friend here, see [working link](https://plnkr.co/edit/dirQzoE5lEGNahQifpA3?p=preview) here.

```
$scope.bordercolor = "thick dotted #ff0000";

<div class="circle-icon" ng-style ="{'border-bottom': bordercolor}">
    <span class="icon icon-loanaccount"></span>
</div>
```